# 7-zip - System volume information\ : Access is denied

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, zip, 7-zip

I am trying to zip with 7z.exe a directory with its subdirectories in Windows 7. I have tried:

> d:\website\
>
> d:\website
>
> \website

But they all give the same warning:

> d:\System Volume Information\ : Access is denied.
>
> ---
>
> WARNING: Cannot find 1 file

This is the bat file I am using. What am I doing wrong?

```
rem @ECHO OFF
rem date in format yyyy-mm-dd    
set today=%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%

d:
cd\
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip website-%today%.zip d:\website\ -mm=Deflate64 -mfb=258 -mpass=15 -r -mx9 -xr!docs
```

Comment: Have you tried `d:\website\*`? All the examples I'm seeing for zipping a directory use a wild card.

Comment: @DavidWoodward It got rid of the error but included the directory `d:\myfiles\Website - other` and all its subdirectories. Not only that, but in the zip file it shows up under the root with the directory name `website`. How can I limit it to the `d:\website\*` folder? It seems odd to have matched this other directory

Comment: From 7zip help: The "base_archive_name" must be the first filename on the command line after the command.

The switches and other filenames can be in any order.

Wildcards or filenames with spaces must be quoted:

    "Dir\Program files\*"
    Dir\"Program files"\*

Comment: @maudam - Thanks for the reply. You will notice that this is after the switches. `7z <command> [<switch>...] <base_archive_name> [<arguments>...]`. a -tzip are switches, so the base archive name is the first filename on the command line.

Comment: parameter -mfb give me error. Test this: "c:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe" a -tzip website-%today%.zip d:\website\*.* -mm=Deflate64 -mpass=15 -r -mx9 -xr!docs

Comment: @DavidWoodward - For some reason (likely user error) specifying d:\website\* appears to work. Thank you.

Comment: @maudam - It appears the `*` in `d:\website\*` is all I needed. The -mfb did not change anything for me. Thanks.